# Don't show the welcome message if you're viewing from Google's cache

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, google

If I'm viewing the site from Google's cache webcache.googleusercontent.com, don't show the welcome message such as "Welcome to Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers — check out the FAQ!".

It's not very relevant if you're unable to interact with the site, and many people receiving the message already know how to interact with the site.

Comment: Is that really necessary?

Answer (score 11):

Why should we optimize our JavaScript for the case that a different website – be it Google's cache or anything else – includes it?

Comment: To improve the user experience. The message is a distraction.